# ggplot time scale breaks: scale_*_time

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a df that I would like to plot with ggplot2 so that the time on the y axis with major breaks at 1 hour and minor breaks at 15 minutes. The time is in the hms class. The default plot only labels the major break at 1 hour.

I intended to use scale_y_time and have read ?scale_y_time, however the documentation speaks mainly to date breaks and not time. I have used this function before for dates and "1 week" or "1 month" works for assigning breaks. I can not find any examples of what the appropriate strings are to use for a time break and my guesses of "1 hour" or "60 minutes" do not seem to work.

```
ggplot()+
geom_tile(c1, mapping = aes(c1$PROV_NAME, c1$time_of_day, fill = c1$session_grouper), stat = "identity")+
  scale_y_time(name = waiver(), breaks = "1 Hour",
           minor_breaks = waiver(), labels = waiver(), limits = NULL,
           expand = waiver(), na.value = NA_real_,
           position = "left", sec.axis = waiver())
```

When running the above code the axis label remains but the major break labels disappear and the following error appears multiple times: In structure(as.numeric(x), names = names(x)) : NAs introduced by coercion

Is there a better reference for the syntax that I should be using to assign a minor time break? Any help would be appreciated.